# How to check if Resultset empty or not

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

i wrote the below code to retrieve all the records from the table, but as i created a new table, i want to check if the ResultSet is empty or not to display a message if it is empty.

how can i do that

**code**:

```
public void selectAll() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

if (this.isTableExists(this.TABLE_NAME)) {

    Connection conn = this.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet resSet = stmt.executeQuery("select * from "+this.TABLE_NAME+";");//i want to check if it is empty or not.

    while (resSet.next()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "ID: "+resSet.getString(ID_COL));
        Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "Node: "+resSet.getString(NODE_ID_COL));
        Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "Lat: "+resSet.getString(LAT_COL));
        Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "Lng: "+resSet.getString(LNG_COL));
        Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "xmlPath: "+resSet.getString(XML_PATH_COL));
        }

    resSet.close();
    stmt.close();
    conn.close();
    } 

else{
    Log.e(TAG, "selectAll", "table: ["+this.TABLE_NAME+"] does not exist");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your could use a boolean variable :

```
    boolean isEmpty = true;
    while (resSet.next()) {
        isEmpty = false;
        Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "ID: "+resSet.getString(ID_COL));
        Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "Node: "+resSet.getString(NODE_ID_COL));
        Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "Lat: "+resSet.getString(LAT_COL));
        Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "Lng: "+resSet.getString(LNG_COL));
        Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "xmlPath: "+resSet.getString(XML_PATH_COL));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
boolean isEmpty = resSet.next()
```

From javadoc:

> true if the new current row is valid; false if there are no more rows

Comment: If data is present, then it will skip the first row.

Comment: @Harshit you can use `ResultSet.beforeFirst()` or `ResultSet.first()` to get first row.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
if(resSet.next())
{
     do {
            Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "ID: "+resSet.getString(ID_COL));
            Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "Node: "+resSet.getString(NODE_ID_COL));
            Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "Lat: "+resSet.getString(LAT_COL));
            Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "Lng: "+resSet.getString(LNG_COL));
            Log.d(TAG, "selectAll", "xmlPath: "+resSet.getString(XML_PATH_COL));
        }
        while (resSet.next())
}
else
{
      // Message : No Data present   
}
```

Comment: It's rare to find a case where a `do while` loop is the best choice, but this is one.

Answer (score 1):

```
ResultSet rs = statement.execute();
if (!rs.next()){
//ResultSet is empty
}
```

or you may try:

```
boolean empty = true;
while( rs.next() ) {
    // ResultSet processing here
    empty = false;
}

if( empty ) {
    // Empty result set
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!res.next()) // this would run if it's empty
```

If the ResultSet is empty, res.next() would return false otherwise, it would return true. So the if statement I used would run if the ResultSet is empty.